# How to prune skeleton in image using Julia

Tags: image-processing, julia, mathematical-morphology

I've a road skeleton (from thinning) as shown below:

[image]

The original image was

[image]

I couldn't find pruning in Julia. Is there a away to remove small segments (streets) from continuous longer ones (main roads)? The red dots show the corner points whose Index is known.

Comment: Is the expected output like a `w`?

Comment: Since the question includes no code, I would suggest asking it in a forum with wider reach (say python/javascrip/java/c++) communities. If a satisfactory answer is given, translating it to Julia should be a smaller challange.